# show product variations in shop overview (WooCommerce)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm searching for a way to show product variations on the WooCommerce shop (overview) page. The shop is about clothing and I want to display the available sizes underneath the title and price. So when a product is out-of-stock it shouldn't be displayed.

**Example:**
-- PRODUCT IMAGE --
PRODUCT NAME
0.00

*Medium, Extra-Large*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following code to functions.php, then play around with CSS to show the variations in a way you like most.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'pixelarchitect_select_variations' );

function pixelarchitect_select_variations() {
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin available that displays product variations in a popup. When you click on select options, it will open a popup instead.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-product-variations-popup